# Best Way to Display/Navigate Hierarchical Data on iPad

Tags: mobile, ipad, hierarchy

On mobile phones there is a straightforward pattern how to display hierarchical data (for example coming from a relational database):

[image: Navigating Hierarchical Data with Tables]

How would I transform this pattern to a tablet and make use of the additional space?

For example, on an iPad there is the UISplitViewController but I am not sure how I would map the lists above to master and detail view.

**EDIT:** Based on Izhaki's recommendation I am making this more concrete:

[image: Concrete Example: Navigation in Workout App]

Comment: It is next to impossible to answer this without specifics - what are the items? What's on level 1/2/3? What other things you need to show. If there would be a definite answer to a generic question like this, there would be no need for UX experts.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I tried to make my question more concrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is allow for the secondary content display to appear next to the selected item. This would give your users the same flow as with your mobile version, but allow for the space allotted by the larger screen.

[image: Workout Hierarchical Data - Tablet]

Comment: I really like this solution, thanks! Sorry for the late reply.